# Open dialog box when I click a button.

Tags: jquery, perl

Hi, I want to open a dialog box when I click a button.
Here is my code:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({ autoOpen: false });

        $('#btn3').click(
            function () {
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                return false;
            }
        );
```

And div button

```
print $q->div({-id =>'dialog', -title => 'Profile'});

my $bt3   = $q->image_button({-src => '/media/images/edit_1.png',
                        -class => 'upd', 
                        -title => 'update', 
                        -name  => 'update',
                        -value => $aArray->[$i]->{'ID'},
                        - id   =>'btn3',
                        -onclick =>"window.location.href = 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css;'", 
               });
```

it shows me a blank page without any error in it.

Comment: Did you check your server's error log?

Answer (score 0):

i presume -onclick should not refer to a location.href change to a css-file, but rather be removed entirely? (ie take away the entire row with -onclick...)